# No operator "*" matches these operands in C++

Tags: c++, operators

I have to code a program which takes as input a medicine's name and its quantity from the user. Then it must calculate the quantity with the given value. However, I am getting an error with the "*" (multiply operator).  The error is given below.

> `Error: no operator "*" matches these operands`
>   `operator types are: std::string * int`

Please help me solve this. I've also attached my code where you can also see the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEuVH.png) clearly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
void main()
{
    string med,quantity,panadol=0,piozer=0,burofen=0;

    cout << "Pharmacy Management System" ;

    cout << "\n Enter your Medicine Name : ";
    getline(cin,med);   

    cout << "\n Enter your Medicine Quantity : ";
    getline(cin,quantity);

    int a,b;

    if (med==panadol && med==burofen)
    {
        a= (quantity*2);
        cout << a;
    }
    if (med==piozer)
    {
        b= (quantity*14);
        cout << b;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal* .  Things like print statements aren't required to reproduce your issue and should be removed.  Also make sure to post the entire error message, including the line number.

Comment: `std::string` stores **text**. How would you multiply text by `14`? I assume that you want to first parse that string to a numeric value. You might be interested in [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Or how about making quantity an int?

Comment: I try to to make quantity an int but getting an another error "invalid null operator" .

Comment: C++ can't be learned by guessing. A good [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is in order.

Comment: Well, you'd have to change the input mechanism; you'd probably still read the line into a string, but then convert the string into an integer.  Or, at a pinch, you'd use `cin >> quantity;` but that would leave the newline in the input stream.  Read as string and convert is probably best.

Comment: @SKHassan Ask yourself the right question. What is the correct type of `quantity`? Obviously a quantity is a number, so it should be an `int` not a `string`. Now make `quantity` an `int` and solve the `"invalid null operator"` problem, whatever that is.

Comment: But how to solve "invalid null operator" problem?

Comment: I just solve  "invalid null operator" problem by making some changing in my codes but now i am not getting any output.

Comment: @SKHassan But your changes were **wrong** and now your code is even further from being correct. Like another poster said you cannot program by guessing. Just because an error goes away doesn't mean you have solved it.

Comment: @SKHassan What I'm saying is don't try and fix errors you don't understand. Try and understand the error first.

Comment: @john you are right i have to understand first.

Comment: @SKHassan Well I hope you find my answer useful.

Comment: @john you answer is helpful and i understand my all error but program doesn't print output just take input from user but doesn't generate output.

Comment: @john i just make all the changing in my code that was told by you in the answer but now i am not getting output result.

Comment: @SKHassan With out seeing your latest code I can't guess what is wrong. So you should ask a new question with your new code (don't add the new code to this question).

Comment: @john just give me few minutes i will post my latest code.

Comment: @john Thanks! I just solve the problem and now my program is printing output your answer is very helpful to me thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some basic misunderstandings in your code. You have to decide what is a variable and what is not, and when you use a variable you have to decide what *type* it is.

There seem to be three basic errors in your code

```
string med,quantity,panadol=0,piozer=0,burofen=0;
```

`panadol`, `poizer` and `burofen` are names of medicines that you want to see if the user entered. So they should not be *variables* they should be *string literals*. Like this

```
if (med == "piozer")
{
    b= (quantity*14);
    cout << b;
}
```

See "piozer" is a string literal and the code above asks if `med` equals "piozer". So delete the `piozer` variable and replace with a string literal, same with all the other medicine names. This is the solution to your `invalid null operator` problem.

Second error is that `quantity` should be an `int`. This should be obvious, you want to multiply quantities, how can you multiply a string?

Third error is here

```
if (med == "panadol" && med == "burofen")
```

It cannot be true that `med` equals "panadol" and `med` equals "burofen". It's logically impossible for one variable to be equal to two different values at the same time. Clearly what you really meant is this

```
if (med == "panadol" || med == "burofen")
```

If `med` equals "panadol" OR `med` equals "burofen", i.e. if either one is true, not if both are true.

Answer (score 0):

`Quantity` is a `string`, `2` is an `int`.  You can't `*` together a `string` and an `int`.

Maybe you want to `stoi` on `quantity`?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `quantity` is a string. You are getting an error because of your attempt to multiply a string by a number. Instead of using the function `getLine()`, that should be used to retrieve strings, try to do it like below:

```
cin >> quantity;
```